# error in displaying all categories on portfolio page in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating portfolio page using template called portfolio.php in this template using below code.
i want to show all categories and portfolio on the page .

reference link:- https://www.thewritersforhire.com/portfolio/

exact same like this page above.

only one array is showing  but in my page its showing 1 category i.e. All

code i have used:

```
<?php

$alltags = [];

$args = [
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'hierarchical'   => 1,
    'exclude'        => '',
    'include'        => '',
    'meta_key'       => '',
    'meta_value'     => '',
    'authors'        => '',
    'child_of'       => 0,
    'parent'         => $id,
    'exclude_tree'   => '',
    'number'         => '',
    'offset'         => 0,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'cat'            => 399,
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$pages = $query->posts;

foreach ($pages as $page) {

    // echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($page);
    //echo "</pre>";

    //$meta = get_post_meta($page->ID, '', true);

    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($page->ID);

    if ($tags) {

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {

            // $tag->name = str_replace('&amp;', "", $tag->name);

            array_push($alltags, $tag->name);

        }
    }

}

$uniquetag = array_unique($alltags);
asort($uniquetag);
array_unshift($uniquetag, 'All');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($uniquetag);
echo "</pre>";
?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="toolbar mb2 mt2">
                    <?php
if ($uniquetag) {
    foreach ($uniquetag as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 'Addhomeportfolio') {} else {
            ?>
    <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="<?php $string = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            echo $string                                            = str_replace('&amp;', "", $string);?>"><?php echo $value; ?></button>
                        <?php
}}
}
?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `"numberposts" => -1,` the code in your $args

Comment: Regarding your requirement, you might need to create a custom post type called portfolio with custom taxonomy. So you can easily manipulate the data and will not touch the page. I recommend CPTUI plugin. I also use that plugin.

Comment: Glad I could help. An Upvote would be much appreciated. :)